# How to avoid resending emails or missing emails in this case?

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, transactions

```
dataContext.saveSend(true);
SendEmailsToAllMembers();
```

I have the code above, if after half of the emails were sent out, there is a error in smtp, then how can I avoid resending emails or missing emails in this cases ?

Comment: If that's all the code that you have, there is absolutely no way you can avoid the resending.

Comment: certainly not all the code, I just omit the content of those functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the SendEmailsToAllMembers you could store which emails have been successfully sent to. Repeat calls to the method could check if this email has already been sent successfully and therefore not resend it.

Comment: That's good idea, but how can I use transaction in .net to protect this ?